# Java formatter - setting file directory

Tags: java, file-handling

i am trying to create a text file in a folder (called AMCData). The file is called "File" (for the sake of this example).

I have tried using this code:

```
public static void OpenFile(String filename)
{
    try
    {
        f = new Formatter("AMCData/" + filename + ".txt");          
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("error present");
    }
}
```

But before i get the chance to even place any text in it, the catch keeps being triggered..
Could anyone inform me why this is occuring?

more information:

- The folder does not exist, i was hoping it would automatically create it
- If it doesn't automatically create folders, could you please link me to how to do so?

Comment: The down votes are probably because you either didn't look at the Exception thrown (`e`), or if you did, you should have told us what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, a `Formatter(String)` constructor needs the file to be present or createable. The most likely reason why a file cannot be created is that it references a folder that itself doesn't exist, so you should use the `File.mkdirs()` method, like this:

```
new File("AMCData").mkdirs();
```

Comment: gah, can't accept answer for 8 minutes, but i will make sure i do

Comment: make sure to check the return value of `mkdirs` to see if was successful